# Why redirects happens on missing of a trailing slash (/) from the URL ?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, http-status-code-301, trailing-slash

One of the most wasteful redirects happens when a trailing slash (/) is missing from a URL that should otherwise have one.For example, going to *http://example.com/action* results in a 301 response containing a redirect to *http://example.com/action/* (notice the added trailing slash).

So what is the cause behind it and how to solve it in case of an Asp.Net application.Any Idea!!

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the `StaticFileHandler` in asp.net, so I don't think you can change it (easily). This is just what the default HTTP handler for static files does.

The source of the behavior is the below line which may be found in applicationhost.config:

```
<add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule">
```

I suspect that the specific module here causing the redirect is `DefaultDocumentModule`, but that would require further investigation to confirm.

You can test that by removing `DefaultDocumentModule`, changing this line to

```
<add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DirectoryListingModule">
```

It will probably break your website, but the redirect will go away.

Comment: I confirm this happening in failed trace logging when I have a rewrite rule to remove the trailing slash and the folder does not have a default document.  Now I just need to figure out how to make it stop. I would expect a 404 instead of a 301 which causes a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is actually a good thing and is recommended on the web.
From nibbler test website: "Search engines might see these as separate pages with duplicate content which they could penalise for."

301 (permanent redirection) only happens once on the server btw. It is cached by the user's browser and the user will be directed to the correct one without needing the server again. so don't worry about this too much (it's not like it's a 302-temporary redirect)

But i'm also curious where this happens. I don't immediately see this in my routing. if anyone knows, please share.

UPDATE: apperently you have this property

```
routes.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
```

maybe that is causing the effect?

Answer (score 0):

Its following Unix path logic. a URI without a trailing slash is pointing to a file and with a trailing slash is directory.

If you are hitting a URI with a trailing slash and on your server you have set the directory listing you will see all the files under that path. Otherwise, a redirect either 301 or 302 could be thrown to indicate that the client need to send a request using another location.

From the clients perspective these 2 URIs might be the same on the web. As a result the server most of the times instead of failing will redirect to another location. Of course it is configurable.

Although I'm not an expert in ASP but definitely the redirection can be controlled on the server either as a config or programatically.